# how to access array of $refs in vue 3 composition api?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I created a dynamic form using Vue 3 that consists of five input text fields. Each input field should only accept a single-digit number. When a user enters a number in an input field, the focus should automatically move to the next input field. After filling in all the input fields, the form should be submitted. In the HandleInput function, I want to access each input field in order to set the focus to the next input field, submit the form, and access the value of each input field. However, I am currently encountering an issue where 'this.$refs' is undefined.

Please provide a solution to access the input fields to achieve the desired functionality.

```js
setup() {
        const inputs= ref(["", "", "", "", ""])

        const handleInput = (index) => {
            if ( index < inputs.value.length - 1) {
                //Error:
                this.$refs['input' + (index + 1)][0].focus();
                console.log(inputs.value[index])

            }
        }

        return {
            inputs,
            handleInput
        }
    }
```

```html
<div v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="input"
          @input="handleInput(index)"
          :ref="'input' + index"
          maxlength="1"
          pattern="[0-9]"/>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you expect `this.$refs` to contain?

Comment: Sorry. I know that I mixed up  some concept  between Vue 2 and 3. But I can find how to solve it. I appreciate you if you could  help me.

Comment: My point is, what did you expect it to contain - I was not pointing out the obvious

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3, you cannot use `this.$refs` inside the `setup()` function because the `setup()` function itself doesn't have access to the Vue instance (`this`). Instead, you should use the `ref` function to create refs for your input fields and access them directly. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired functionality:

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="input"
      @input="handleInput(index)"
      :ref="'input' + index"
      maxlength="1"
      pattern="[0-9]"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const inputs = ref(["", "", "", "", ""]);

    const handleInput = (index) => {
      if (index < inputs.value.length - 1) {
        const nextInput = document.querySelector(`#input${index + 1}`);
        if (nextInput) {
          nextInput.focus();
        }
      }
      console.log(inputs.value[index]);
    };

    return {
      inputs,
      handleInput,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

In this modified code, we're using `document.querySelector` to directly access the input field by its ID, based on the index provided to the `handleInput` function. We no longer rely on `this.$refs` since we're working within the `setup()` function. This should allow you to set focus to the next input field, access the value of each input field, and achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Sounds like a ChatGPT answer.